# How to ignore all whitespace issues when using dotnet format?

Tags: dotnet-cli, dotnet-format

## How to ignore all whitespace issues when using dotnet format?

I've generated an `.editorconfig` with mostly default options using [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022#code-styles-in-editorconfig-files).

When I run this command...

```
dotnet format .\<SLN_NAME>.sln --verify-no-changes
```

...I see errors like: `<ABSOLUTE_FILE_PATH>\file.cs(1,1): error WHITESPACE: Fix whitespace formatting. Replace <N> characters with '<A_BUNCH_OF_SPACES>'`.

I looked through the `.editorconfig` settings to try to find the source of the issue, and I reviewed [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options) but I don't see anything that looks helpful.

Is there a way I can silence these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you review [this readme](https://github.com/dotnet/format#how-to-use), you'll notice that you can use subcommands to target specific issues, one of which is `whitespace`.

This means you can run the commands below to target the non-whitespace subcommands, thus effectively ignoring your whitespace issues:

```
dotnet format style .\<SLN_NAME>.sln --verify-no-changes 
dotnet format analyzers .\<SLN_NAME>.sln --verify-no-changes
```