# dotnet format changes the encoding of the file

Tags: .net, unicode, removing-whitespace, subcommand, dotnet-format

I am using dotnet format command to do code analysis with certain IDE's in the .editorconfig file.
However, some of the files I see in my git changes are just encoding changes and no text changes in the code. This is the error on the top of the files:

"these files have different encodings. left file: unicode (utf-8) with signature. right file: unicode (utf-8) without signature. you can resolve the difference by saving the right file with the encoding unicode (utf-8) with signature. click to learn more"

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986895/how-to-ignore-all-whitespace-issues-when-using-dotnet-format) which suggest to remove the whitespace subcommand.

However, doing this also removes the trivial whitespace issues defined in my .editorconfig file like 'insert space after comma'.

How can I remove the unicode changes but also keep the original whitespace formatting when running the dotnet format command.